# Securely determining what tokens have been minted?

Tags: dapps, events, mint

I am working on a ERC721 based application that is related to an offchain web app. I am trying to figure out how to have the DAPP securely tell the web app when a token is minted.

My original (simple) plan was to emit an event onMint from the contract to JS DAPP which would handle the request and subsequently call the web app's REST api.  However, this isn't really secure because a user with a JS debugger will easily be able to make a call to the server and could claim that a token was minted that wasn't.

Curious what techniques could be used to solve this use case.

Comment: The authority that determines what tokens have been minted is the blockchain. No matter what the user changes on your front end will make the blockchain say otherwise. Your event approach seems fine to me, just double check on the server side if you want but one way or another you have to take the blockchain word for it.

Comment: When you say double check on the server side do you mean have the server check the chain?  Doing so will cost gas each time right?

Comment: Yes the server can check the chain, but you can do a simple call to check the blockchain state, no need to send a transaction.  You'd be calling a view function to check that this token exists.